# Want to add a field to a python scrapy output like a Serial number which increment by 1 for each product scraped

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to **scrape** a website using Scrappy tool for Python.

I am able to **scrape** the data but

I want to add an additional field to the output
like a "Serial ID" : "3001",
for each product it **scrapes**
the Serial ID should increment by 1, like 3002, 3003, 3004.............

```
def parse_dir_contents(self,response):
    cat = response.meta['cat']
    serial_id = I
    item = []
    content = {}
    
    content['serial_id'] = serial_id
    content['url'] = response.url
    content['category'] = cat
    brand = response.xpath('//div[@class="pageinfo__brdcrmb"]/text()').extract()[0].split('/')
    content['brand'] = brand[1].strip()
    I = I + 1
    item.append(content)
    output = json.dumps(item, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
    self.json_file.write(output)
```

For the above Code I am getting an error like

content['url'] = response.url
NameError: name 'response' is not defined

Comment: could you fix the indentation in the question ? not sure where the function `parse_dir_contents`ends

Answer (score 0):

name `I` in third line is not defined.
change it to

```
serial_id = 1
```

and then increase that with:

```
serial_id += 1
```

You can use scrapy benefits ( like pipeline, define items and ... ) and keep your code tidy.

read this helpful documents:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/